# Pass result of $.getJSON to another method of the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, class, methods

I have a JavaScript-class and want to pass the result of $.getJSON to another method of the same class and access it from outside the class. Where is my mistake?

My code is similar like this:

```
function MyClass() {
    var mydata = false;

    this.getData = function() {
        $.getJSON( "/api/get.php", function(data) {
            this.setData(data);
        });
    }

    this.setData = function(data) {
        this.mydata = data;
        this.logData();
    } 

    this.logData = function() {
        console.log(this.mydata);
    }   

    this.returnData = function() {
        return this.mydata;
    } 
}

var MyClass = new MyClass();
MyClass.getData();
var data = MyClass.returnData();
```

First I want to create an instance of my class and get the data from server. Then the method setData should verify the result, store it in a variable and log the result to console. After this I want to access the data from outside the class.

Answer (score 0):

`this` changes within every function, so you could store `this` inside a variable:

```
function MyClass() {
    var mydata = false, that = this;

    this.getData = function() {
        $.getJSON( "/api/get.php", function(data) {
            that.setData(data);
        });
    }

    this.setData = function(data) {
        that.mydata = data;
        that.logData();
    } 

    this.logData = function() {
        console.log(that.mydata);
    }   

    this.returnData = function() {
        return that.mydata;
    } 
}

var MyClass = new MyClass();
MyClass.getData();
var data = MyClass.returnData();
```

Comment: Thx! I simply forgot this!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    function MyClass(){

var setValue="",logValue="";

var getJSON = function(setDatafunc){
    $.getJSON( "http://demo3913311.mockable.io/mytestdata", function(data) {
        setDatafunc(data);
    });
}

var getData = function(){
    return getJSON(setData);
}

var setData = function(data) {
         setValue = (data)? data: (setValue)? setValue : 'undefined'
         logData(setValue);
} 

var logData= function(data){
    logValue = (data)? data: (logValue)? logValue : 'undefined'
    console.log('12',logValue)
    return logValue;
}

var returnData = function(){
    return logValue;
}



return {

    get: getData,
    set: setData,
    //log: logData
    doReturn : returnData
}

}

var MyClass = new MyClass();
MyClass.get()
MyClass.doReturn();
```